# Display drivers have stopped responding and has recovered

Tags: cpu

I recently purchased this http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=1723935&CatId=7182
I installed it and started experiencing some serious problems. When i do anything slightly stressful on the system (mostly gaming) the game runs fine but after a few minutes (sometimes seconds) into gaming the screen will freeze, go black, then come back again. I get a pop up that says "Display drivers have stopped working and have recovered". This is extremely aggravating and stressful for me seeing as ive read a few things on this problem and all the trouble shooting ive done has got me no where. Ive tried keeping the system cooler, adjusting the OC, giving the cpu a bit more voltage, updating drivers, and taking the radeon 6450 i had in (with dual graphics enabled). The motherboard i have in here is a Gigabyte A75M-S2V.

Comment: "adjusting the OC" - So your system is overclocked?

Comment: Ah, good old TDR. Well, good luck, I never really solved this issue with my 6950. The only ghetto fix I can recommend is keeping your card's temperature above 55C, I know this sounds weird but the driver reset just stopped occurring above that temperature, and below that, some games and applications would simply instacrash. This is the only reliable fix I found, and it may not work for you, so YMMV.